# Unable to connect to SignalR hub written in ASP.NET 7, client is in Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, signalr, hub

cannot connect to hub.
I am using Angular to connect to my SignalR Hub that is wrote in C# (ASP NET CORE 7)

this is the frontend code :

```
this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("https://localhost:5168/hub-chat",{
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      })
      .build();
```

and this is  backend code
configuration

```
var connectionString = configuration.GetSection(nameof(RedisOptions)).GetChildren().ElementAt(0).Value;

            services.AddSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                options.KeepAliveInterval = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            }).AddStackExchangeRedis(connectionString);
```

and mapping for hub

```
 builder.MapHub<ChatHub>("hub-chat");
```

Comment: Remove the Redis middleware and see if you can connect.

Comment: Javascriot part only builds a connection object. Connection won't be established untill you call connect method and await that

Comment: i am getting the same error when i am removing AddStackExchangeRedis

Comment: yes after building the connection i ma calling this  (this.connection?.start();)

Comment: i mean when you connect to hub successful you will get some connectid. but i am not getting any connectionId

Comment: Try to define the connection like this `this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("https://localhost:5168/hub-chat",{
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      })
       .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug).build();`

Comment: And share the log which you can find from the browser console window.

Comment: HubConnection failed to start successfully because of error 'Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled

Comment: failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Please share the screenshot which may help us to check the issue.

Comment: thanks bro i found what was the problem. the backend project was lauching via http but i provided connection to hub via https ))))